# document type does not allow element "div" here; assuming missing "object" start-tag

Tags: w3c-validation

Error Line 18, Column 19: document type does not allow element "div" here; assuming missing "object" start-tag

Please see the page source below

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title></title>

    <meta name="keywords" content="Karnataka,Bangalore_Rural,Healthcare,Office_Assistant,Kerala,Ernakulam,IT_Hardware_Networking,Engineer,Sales___Marketing,Executive,Maharashtra,Mumbai_City,Retailing,Manager,Kollam,CRM_CallCentres_BPO_ITES_Med.Trans,Customer_Care,Hotel_Travel_Tourism_Airlines_Hospitality,Front_Office_Staff,Andhra_Pradesh,Hyderabad,IT_Software,Java_Developer,Pathanamthitta,Manufacturing_Industrial,Educational_Training,Teacher,Engineering_Projects"/>
    <meta name="description" content="The best job oriented resume sharing system. Create and Publish your online resumes for FREE. Search and apply your dream jobs for FREE. Post your jobs for FREE."/>
    
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>

    

     <div id="fb-root"></div>
```

Comment: <div> is not allowed without <head>. Move it into <body> instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do believe you need to put the < div > inside a < body > section.